# Loading a Class through Generics

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, generics

I am confused with this. But here is what I am trying to do. here is the class structure:

```
public class Order
{
    public Int32 orderID { get; set; }
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Int32 ProductID { get; set; }
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    public Product ProductDetails { get; set; }
    public Customer CustomerDetails { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public Int32 ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Int32 CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

I am building a generic method, that takes an XML content and creates and loads object instance of the passed type. I got the Product and customer working. But when it comes to orders it gets confusing.

```
    public static T LoadObject<T>(string Contents) where T : new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof (T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType || property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
            {
                object propValue = Convert.ChangeType(GetValue(property.PropertyType, Contents),
                                                      property.PropertyType);
                property.SetValue(obj, propValue, null);
            }
            else
            {
                //Type typeArgument = property.PropertyType;
                //Type genericClass = t
                //object propValue = LoadObject<> (dr);
                //property.SetValue(obj, propValue, null);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

How do I call this recursively, for Order to load customer and product?

Comment: Can't you use the XmlSerializer to accomplish this?

Comment: These classes are all fairly small, so I don't quite understand why you need such a universal solution (the YAGNI principle...). I'd just implement some "FromXml" method for each of them, and make it an interface method or something. Take into account that reflection is actually very slow - when you'll have thousands of orders to process, it will be noticeable. Retrieving the same `PropertyInfo`s over and over is costly.

Comment: This is just an example that I came up with to better explain the problem. In reality these are not the classes. And the input need not be XML too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to make recursive calls:

```
public void Test<T>()
{
    var methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod("Test");
    methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
    methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you cannot call `LoadObject<T>` where `T` would be of `property.PropertyType`, because you can't use generics with parameter unknown at compile time. I faced such an issue myself and I once asked a question somewhat related to your problem: [Generic static class - retrieving object type in run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883741/generic-static-class-retrieving-object-type-in-run-time) (related - if I understood you well, that is. Otherwise disregard it).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, what you would do in this situation is create Customer and Product instances within the Order class, and use a Load method on the order class to populate the Order, and then populate the Customer instance and the Product instance.

```
public class Order
{  
   public void LoadOrder(int orderID)
   {
       //load order

       //load customer from order

       //load product from order
   }

   public Customer Cust
   {
      get; set;
   }
   public Product Prod
   {
      get; set;
   }
}
```

I know what you were asking was a little different, but hopefully this helps.