# Handle generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

```
class Order { ... }

class OrderA : Order { ... }

class OrderB : Order { ... }

class OrderC : Order { ... }

class OrderD : Order { ... }


private Order GetOrder() { ... }
```

How can i have a method that dynamically casts the returned Order object to any of the specific ones:

```
private T GetSpecificOrder<T>(T order) : where T : Order
{
    ...
}
```

And i wanna call it like:

```
var myOrder = GetOrder();
var specificOrder = GetSpecificOrder<Order>(myOrder);
HandleOrder(specificOrder);
```

I want that specificOrder object is instantiated as one of the sub classes so i can call it like this:

```
HandleOrder(OrderA o) { ... }
HandleOrder(OrderB o) { ... }
HandleOrder(OrderC o) { ... }
HandleOrder(OrderD o) { ... }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the order returned from `GetOrder` is not the correct type, you cannot just cast it A or B. You have to actually do mapping and instantiate the correct type. You can't cast upwards if the type doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting overload resolution to occur at execution time. That doesn't happen... unless you use `dynamic`, which may well be the simplest solution for you:

```
dynamic order = GetOrder(orderId);
HandleOrder(order); // The right overload will be picked at execution time
```

Another alternative would be to use [double-dispatch / the visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch), but personally I find that a bit clunky.

Another alternative would be to make a `Dictionary<Type, Action<Order>>` like this:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<Order>> orderHandlers = 
    new Dictionary<Type, Action<Order>>
{
    { typeof(OrderA), order => HandleOrder((OrderA) order) },
    { typeof(OrderB), order => HandleOrder((OrderB) order) },
    { typeof(OrderC), order => HandleOrder((OrderC) order) },
    { typeof(OrderD), order => HandleOrder((OrderD) order) },
};
```

Then just fetch the relevant delegate and call it:

```
orderHandlers[order.GetType()](order);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this: 
bool result = orderHandlers[order.GetType()](order);   ??

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: Sure, just change it from `Action<Order>` to `Func<Order, bool`>. (Your question didn't show anything about the return types of the methods...)

Comment: Pretty much like http://stackoverflow.com/a/6883766/168719 (I used to have a similar problem)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with generics: whatever goes into the angle brackets must be a type that is known at compile time, so this line

```
var specificOrder = GetSpecificOrder<Order>(myOrder);
```

will require a cast to become `OrderA`, `OrderB`, etc.

However, there are at least two ways to work around the situation:

1. Use the [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) by adding an `Accept` method to the `Order` and its subclasses, or
2. By using `dynamic`, in which case the runtime will perform the correct dispatch for you.

Here is how to implement the #1:

```
interface IOrderHandler {
    void HandleOrder(OrderA o);
    void HandleOrder(OrderB o);
    void HandleOrder(OrderC o);
    void HandleOrder(OrderD o);
}
abstract class Order { abstract void Accept(IOrderHandler h); }

class OrderA : Order { void Accept(IOrderHandler h) {h.HandleOrder(this);} }

class OrderB : Order { void Accept(IOrderHandler h) {h.HandleOrder(this);} }

class OrderC : Order { void Accept(IOrderHandler h) {h.HandleOrder(this);} }

class OrderD : Order { void Accept(IOrderHandler h) {h.HandleOrder(this);} }

...

var myOrder = GetOrder();
IOrderHandler handler = ... // Obtain the handler
myOrder.Accept(handler);    // This will call the correct HandleOrder
```

Here is how to implement the #2:

```
dynamic myOrder = GetOrder();
HandleOrder(myOrder); // Will dispatch based on the runtime type
```

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 so i guess dynamic is out of the question right?

Comment: @HélderGonçalves Right, `dymamic` is not available until 4.0. But the visitor is language-neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
private T GetSpecificOrder<T>(T order)
    {
     return (T)Convert.ChangeType(T, typeof(T));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call GetSpecificOrder as the desired derived classed:

```
var specificOrder = GetSpecificOrder<OrderA>(myOrder);
```

Or cast it:

```
var specificOrder = (OrderA)GetSpecificOrder<Order>(myOrder);
```

And then you can assign whatever properties are unique to the given derived class.